# WinApi: Calculate ListView height

Tags: winapi, listview, vb6

I have a VB6 listview in Details mode, showing X number of items. I want to create some kind of auto-height function that evaluates the height based on a specified width and the number of items.

The following code DID NOT work:

```
Public Declare Function MessageSend Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Const LVM_FIRST As Long = &H1000
Public Const LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT    As Long = (LVM_FIRST + 64)

Public Sub GetAutoWidth(lvw as ListView)
    result = MakeLPAram(-1, 0)
    MessageSend lvw.hWnd, LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT, -1&, result
    lvw.height = loWord(result) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
End Sub

Public Function LoWord(value As Long) As Long
    LoWord = (value And &HFFFF&)
End Function

Public Function MakeLPAram(wLow As Long, wHigh As Long) As Long
    MakeLPAram = MakeLong(wLow, wHigh)
End Function

Public Function MakeLong(wLow As Long, wHigh As Long) As Long
    MakeLong = LoWord(wLow) Or (&H10000 * LoWord(wHigh))
End Function
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: returned 65535 for the low-word and 0 for the hi-word.

Comment: Please restate your comment in terms of values of your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not save return value of [`LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774883.aspx) message here:

```
MessageSend lvw.hWnd, LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT, -1&, result
```

You should, as return value is exactly why you send the message in the first place:

> Return value
>
> Returns a DWORD value that holds the approximate width (in the LOWORD)
>   and height (in the HIWORD) needed to display the items, in pixels.

Second, your naming (`GetAutoWidth`), title of your question ("Calculate ListView height"), and your code (`lvw.height = loWord(result) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX`) are quite inconsistent.

Third, read the following MSDN articles as your code for packing/unpacking words and double-words is flawed too:

[How to Mimic HIWORD, LOWORD, HIBYTE, LOBYTE C Macros in VB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112651)

[How To Package HiWord/LoWord Values Into a Long Parameter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189170)